# Partial view doesn't call Http Post Method

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, partial-views

So I created a partial log in in my homepage. The form gets rendered properly, however it doesn't call the http post action result whenever I submit the form. Please see the below code for reference.

HomePage:

```
<header class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">


        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href="@Url.Action("HomePage", "Home")" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Branchlist", "Branch")" class="nav-link">BRANCH</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <div> @{Html.RenderAction("LogInBox");}</div>>
        </form>
    </div>
</header>
```

Log In Partial

```
@model BBLoyalty.Models.LoyaltyAccountModel

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("LogInBox", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="form-row align-items-center">

<div class="col-auto">
    <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Username</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> </div>
        </div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Username, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Username", autofocus = "autofocus" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-auto">
    <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Username</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i> </div>
        </div>
        @Html.PasswordFor(s => s.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-auto">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mb-2">Log In</button>
</div>
</div>

}
```

HomeController.cs

```
    public ActionResult LogInBox()

    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogInBox(LoyaltyAccountModel acn)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            LoyaltyAccount ua = bbdb.LoyaltyAccounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == acn.Username && x.IsActive == true);
            if (ua != null)
            {
                string ep = eh.GetEncrypted(acn.Password, acn.Username);

                if (ua.Password == ep && ua.Type != "") // Needs to Identify the type of Account(Client/Admin) Otherwise Cannot Login
                {

                    Session["ActiveUser"] = ua.UserId;

                    if (ua.Type == "Admin" || ua.Type == "SuperUser")
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Maintenance");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Incorrect Password!";

                    return View();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Account!";

                return View();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Upon submission, it doesn't call the ActionResult LogInBox(LoyaltyAccountModel acn)

Please Help. It always calls the first ActionResult, the one without the parameter.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m99D3.png)

Comment: How do you confirm that it is not submitting? Did you put a breakpoint in Action method and try to debug the code?

Comment: You have nested <form> tags, one in Home and another in partial. Nested forms are not supported. You can have multiple forms in a single page, but not nested within each other.

Comment: Yes I did, as I have stated the first ActionResult is always the one that gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have form tag in Home and another form tag in partial, this generates nested forms at runtime which is not supported.

Remove the form tag from the below code.

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <div> @{Html.RenderAction("LogInBox");}</div>>
</form>
```

Comment: You're a hero my friend. I didn't paid attention to that detail. I finally get it to work. I've been melding with this for a couple of hours.